# Is it possible to have two fragment xml in one activity xml?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I am trying to make a welcome activity that has header fragment xml and bottom view fragment xml that contains buttons to login. Can anyone help me how I will put this two fragment xml to my `activity_main.xml`?

This is my `header.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="220dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/header_bg" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right|end"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/android_spaces_large"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/android_spaces_large"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/android_spaces_large"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/android_spaces_large"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/android_spaces">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/header_title"
            style="@style/Header.TitleText" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subtitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/header_subtitle"
            style="@style/Header.SubTitleText" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@android:id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"
        android:background="@layout/header_ab_shadow" />



</FrameLayout>
```

And my `fragment_bottomview.xml` that contains only a single button.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And my `activity_main.xml` looks like this

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.windows81.welcomingwithheader.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

I don't know what I am lacking or I am doing wrong, any tutorial link will really help me.

Comment: Use a Relative Layout. Add a fragment at the top and relative to that you can have another fragment below it

Comment: why do you need fragments at all? if you don't how to use fragments its most likely you don't need them...

Comment: @Raghunandan i'll change my framelayout on activity_main.xml to Relative layout?

Comment: @pskink Is there any way i can implement header and have buttons at the bottom part of it?

Comment: see http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html on how you can use child layout xml files in parent layout xml file

Comment: @Raghunandan i saw many finished project of list view with a header, but i don't want a list view at the bottom and header scrolling. Just a header image and button at the bottom of the image. I'll try to look at pskink's link.

Comment: @KeanPadua sorry listview is not condusive for what you want. You can just include the layouts in `activity_main.xml`. Also i don't think you require fragments also for what you want

Answer (score 0):

just make two new classes ,lets call them FragmentA and FragmentB and both should extend fragment

than override onCreateView for both fragmentA and fragmentB and set their view to your xml to the header.xml and fragment_bottomview.xml as shown below

```
  public class FragmentA extends Fragment {

 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle   
savedInstanceState) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.header,container,false);

    return view;
}


}


public class FragmentB extends Fragment {

 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle   
savedInstanceState) {
    View view; 
    view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bottomview,container,false);

    return view;
}


}
```

and now to add FragmentA and FragmentB into your activity,put this code in your oncreate activity method

```
    FragmentA fragmentA=new FragmentA();
    FragmentManager manager=getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction trans=manager.beginTransaction();
    trans.add(R.id.container,fragmentA,"fragmenta");/*adding fragment into 
                                                       the 
                                                 framelayout with id   
                                                container*/
   FragmentB fragmentB=new FragmentB();
   trans.add(R.id.container,fragmentB,"fragmentb");/*adding fragment into 
                                                  the 
                                                 framelayout with id   
                                                container*/

    trans.commit();
```

and your probably should use relative layout instead of framelayout

Comment: Where class i will put the last code? On my MainActivity? Or on both Fragment class? And correct me if im wrong, i'll change the framelayout on my activity_main.xml to relativelayout, right?

Comment: put the last code on your MainActivity in your oncreate method and change your framelayout to relativelayout

Comment: @KeanPadua you don't need fragments for what you want to do: see the comments below your question

Comment: @KeanPadua as pskink said your probably don't need fragments,just put them in the same layout but anyway I'll consider using fragment for learning purposes as it will helps you a lot in the future

Comment: @pskink yes. I solved my problem. I just changed framelayout to relativelayout and change the layout_height to match_parent that allows me to have a button under the image. Just like you said, I don't need fragments to this one. Thanks

Comment: @has19 sorry my bad. I based on one of the finished project about listview with header, I thought it will be the same on how it will be implemented